# Google Spreadsheet: Skip empty queries when stacking multiple queries in one sheet

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

**Background**
I am building a spreadsheet query-complex that returns all weekly events automatically. These events are ordered by region, but not all regions will host events every week. I have stacked queries from each region by using semicolons, e.g. {=QUERY();QUERY();QUERY();QUERY()}, each labeled by region name.
The query complex needs to only return queries with actual events.

**Question**
Since there won't necessarily be an event in all regions every week, I will end up with one or more empty queries in my query complex. This will cause my query to only return queries with its label, or, when removing the query labels, cause the query-complex return an error.

**Example**

```
={

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Phantom Row For Titles' order by D asc, C asc label B 'City'",1);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Africa' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Africa'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Asia' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Asia'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Central America' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Central America'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Europe' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Europe'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Middle East' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Middle East'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'North America' order by D asc, C asc label C 'North America'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Oceania' order by D asc, C asc label C 'Oceania'",0);

Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'South America' order by D asc, C asc label C 'South America'",0)

}
```

Here's a working spreadsheet sample, illustrating what I have and what I need:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VnDyxOdw9aJMJpIs7zKSdG3c6fUo-QxDU82zaw-k7Kk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there's no direct way to do that. I suggest a workaround here.

Please try:

```
=QUERY(

{Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Phantom Row For Titles' order by D asc, C asc label B 'City'",1);

IFERROR({"","","Africa","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Africa' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","Asia","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Asia' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","Central America","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Central America' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","Europe","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Europe' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","Middle East","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Middle East' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","North America","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'North America' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","Oceania","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'Oceania' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"});

IFERROR({"","","South America","","";Query(Data!A:O,"Select A,B,C,E,F where D = 'South America' order by D asc, C asc",0)},{"x","x","x","x","x"})},

"select * where Col2 <> 'x'",1)
```

---

My basic logic was to use query 2 times:

1. check the output
2. return the result if an output is more than 2 rows.

This way is bad because it doubles the formula.

---

Then I thought about the different approach:

- When you have no labels and no result, the query would return an error
- so I used `iferror` function and gave fake line `{"x","x","x","x","x"}` when error occurs
- The final query is to skip "x" rows.

Comment: Wait, I found an issue with the formula. When the text in the region row ("","","Region","","") is above a numeric column, it fails to return the text. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: This issue relates to native `query` behavior. Query handles only one data type: number, string, boolean or date. You need to convert the data into text ( `arrayformula(to_text(Data!A:O)`  ) before using a query. Note that query text will need a `Col1, Col2...`notation.

Comment: Transforming the numbers to text is not an option, since I filter for events before/after/between dates.

Comment: I think it is possible to find the solution. Since things are going more complicated, please post another question with a sample file and describe your issue. It surely will help you!

Comment: Issue reported by @Nowak can be resolved by selecting a dummy number in json. For example if your normal data is {"America", 25, "English"}, your dummy data in case of error should be {"x",0,"x"}

Answer (score 0):

Since some regional settings (french settings) in Google Sheets don't allow to use the array literal {"x","x","x"} (that's supposed to generate an array of 1 row and 3 columns with "x" as value) to use as IFERROR value in a series of QUERY formulas.
I used the formula "ARRAY_CONSTRAIN" to generate an array of 1 row and 3 columns in my IFERROR formula.

To do so, you'll use :
={
IFERROR(QUERY('sheet1'!A2:C;"select A,B,C where (A != '')");ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(I1:K1;1;3));
IFERROR(QUERY('sheet2'!A2:C;"select A,B,C where (A != '')");ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(I1:K1;1;3))
}

So that if one of the two queries fail to return data, the values of I1:K1 will be inserted instead and thus will avoid the all formula to fail.